# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dslim/bert-base-NER/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am facing below issue while loading the pretrained BERT model from HuggingFace due to SSL certificate error.

### Error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dslim/bert-base-NER/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))

### The line that is causing the issue is:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
```

### Source code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
```

I am expecting to download pre-trained models while running the code in jupyter lab on Windows.

Comment: You can refer to the answer i have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111104/21000710)

Answer (score 14):

A working solution to this is the following:

1)

```
 pip install requests==2.27.1
```

Please note that both prerequisites need to take place, just running the following code will not work unless you have that specific version of requests (I had to downgrade in my case from `2.29.0` to `2.27.1`.

2)

```
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```

Comment: What if adding requests==2.27.1 introduces several incompability issues with other packages?

Comment: Yeh, Chroma with langchain requries higher version of requests so I could not use this solution.

Answer (score 10):

Try to add the following in your main python file

```
import os

os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution if you want the actual certificate:

If you are on linux you can use this bash script I made to download the certificate file from Cisco Umberella, convert it to .crt and update the certificates folder. Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -O https://d36u8deuxga9bo.cloudfront.net/certificates/Cisco_Umbrella_Root_CA.cer
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in Cisco_Umbrella_Root_CA.cer -out cisco.crt
rm -rf Cisco_Umbrella_Root_CA.cer
sudo mv cisco.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After adding the new certificate from Cisco you still need to set the environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` before using the `from_pretrained` function. This is because the certifi package used by transformers for ca-certification defaults to some .pem file inside the certifi package. We instead set it to the directory your downloaded certificate was just moved to by `update-ca-certificates`. Here is how:

```
import os
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

os.environ["CURL_CA_BUNDLE"] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("intfloat/multilingual-e5-small")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("intfloat/multilingual-e5-small")
```

Now it should download the model without any security warnings. Hope this helped.

Comment: In my case with brew, it was CURL_CA_BUNDLE="~/.homebrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem"

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a firewall issue. For example for some organisations this occurs when using LAN but not with WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution for this is **Enable your device for development**.

> if you're writing software with Visual Studio on a computer for the first time, you will need to enable Developer Mode on both the development PC and on any devices you'll use to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with my linux machine ,Looking at server of hugging face found that they were working fine ,it was just the issue of proxy directly export proxy in .zshrc work for me.

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890
export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

using source ~/.zshrc
I tried downgrading request library but didn't worked ,by managing the proxy it did work for me .

Answer (score 0):

By setting the below environment variables it worked:

```py
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```

Answer (score -1):

conda install onnxruntime -c conda-forge\n

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34679501)