# How to download huggingface bert-base-uncased in China

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I need to use huggingface `bert-base-uncased` in China.

I tried this on my local computer (It has VPN installed), and it is working fine.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM
  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

However, I want to execute/install it on the server to train a model. On server, I have limited (no sudo) access but I use `conda` environments.

I tried this on server:

```
git lfs install
git clone https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased
```

and

```
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
snapshot_download(repo_id="bert-base-uncased")
```

But nothing seems to work and I am getting the https connection error. "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded"

On my personal computer: Git `clone` also did not work in the Pycharm terminal and git desktop.

What other options do I have?
The only option I think I have now is to download it on my personal computer then transfer to the server via FTP and build it there.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110981/sslerror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-huggingface-co-port-443-max-retries-exce

Comment: Try set up a reverse SSH tunnel with your local computer and use environment variable to tell the bash (or whatever shell it uses) on your server to use the tunnel as the proxy.

Comment: Just use mirror site: https://hf-mirror.com