# Hugging face Certificate verification failed

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

I can't get the model downloaded when using the access token. Tried creating a new token but the same error.

```py
model_id='meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf'
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_id,
token=''
)
```

```py
MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn-lfs.huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded

Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))"), '(Request ID: 0c7dac02-e1e6-4de6-a585-0e9581c4a24f)')
```

Tried this but does not work.

```py
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```

Any ideas what is the fix here?

Answer (score 0):

Only solution is to degrade `requests` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76218591/9937932