SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443)
I have the following script:
test.py:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

checkpoint = "kevinscaria/joint_tk-instruct-base-def-pos-neg-neut-combined"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

When I run python test.py I get the following error:

requests.exceptions.SSLError:
(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url:
/kevinscaria/joint_tk-instruct-base-def-pos-neg-neut-combined/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed
certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))"), '(Request ID:
2d2eb919-ddf8-4e5d-b0fc-b0ab1f666251)')

This is despite I already added huggingface.co to my pip configuration file as a trusted host:
>pip config list
global.trusted-host='pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org huggingface.co'

Note that I'm working on a different computer and I'm constantly having this kind of SSL errors which I never had on my previous computer.

The "self-signed certificate" implies there's a proxy or something on that different computer that's using a self-signed certificate. You'll need to figure that out.

Can you give me some direction? I don't even know what a self-signed certificate is.

No, I can't, not without knowing which OS you're on, etc, etc. Also, configuring pip won't help here; this is an issue with how the Huggingface library is downloading things.

Never mind, I added import os and os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = '', and downgraded requests and I solved it. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76218591/7227146.
